# Calculated Field Formula for IF

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I am trying to create a column that would result based on another column.

Example:

If the column titled "company" is a specific company name, the calculated column would return an hourly rate of $135.00.  If the company name is changed, then the calculated column would return a different hourly rate of $50.00.

How do I write this formula?  I keep getting a syntex error.

Comment: Is it fixed value $135 and $50?

Comment: Share formula that you are using

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
=IF(Company="xyz",135,55)
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula would be something like this

```
=IF([CompanyName]="ABC","$135","$50")
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language of your operation system, you may have to use

`=IF([CompanyName]="ABC";"$135";"$50")`

instead of

`=IF([CompanyName]="ABC","$135","$50")`.

(Semicolon instead of coma)

MSDN:

> In some countries, the comma is reserved for use as the decimal mark. In such countries, users creating a calculated field must use semicolons ";" as the delimiter character.